Powershell, write creation of environment variables to file
I have a simple question I am struggling to find answer to.
I want to write next:
"$env:CI_JOB_STAGE = preprocessing" to a file.
I tried with this:
Add-Content -Path test.bat -Value "$env:CI_JOB_STAGE = preprocessing"

What i receive in file is:
 = preprocessing

Thats because I dont have this variable created yet but I want it to be created later when the file will be executed.
What I want to get in the file is:
$env:CI_JOB_STAGE = preprocessing


Add-Content -Path test.bat -Value '$env:CI_JOB_STAGE = "preprocessing"' variables expand in a string with double-quotes. Use single instead.

@SantiagoSquarzon thank a lot!!!!!))))

Variables expand in a string with double-quotes "...", use single-quotes instead '...'. See about_Quoting_Rules for more details.
Add-Content -Path test.bat -Value '$env:CI_JOB_STAGE = "preprocessing"'

The article linked above also explains that if you need to use double-quotes you can escape the variable expansion using a backtick (`):
Add-Content -Path test.bat -Value "`$env:CI_JOB_STAGE = 'preprocessing'"


If you needed to keep the double quotes, you can use the backtick   "`$" to escape the dollar.
